# Angular child component ng-invalid

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm creating a custom input component that's forms compatible by implementing `ControlValueAccessor`. This input component is a composition of one or more child inputs, but I'm having trouble getting the `ng-invalid` CSS class to propagate to the child `input` element.

My custom input component has a template like:

```
<label>Input:</label> <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" (blur)="onInputBlur()" />
```

The class is:

```
private _value: any;

public get value(): string {
  return this._value;
}
public set value(newValue) {
  this._value = newValue;
  this.onChangeCallback(this._value);
}
public onInputBlur() {
  this.onTouchedCallback();
}

private onChangeCallback = (x: any) => { };
private onTouchedCallback = () => { };

writeValue(obj: any): void {
  this._value = obj;
}
registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
  this.onChangeCallback = fn;
}
registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
  this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
}
setDisabledState ? (isDisabled: boolean): void {
}
```

And I'm binding to the custom input component using a reactive form like:

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <my-editor [formControlName]="'myValue'"></my-editor>
</div>
```

The `div` and `my-editor` elements both get the `ng-invalid` class applied, but I can't find an elegant way to get that class applied to the `input` element.

Here's a Stackblitz showing the issue.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-child-ng-invalid

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved your issue by using the below implementation using 'NgControl', using this approach you will make your custom input modular which can be used as and when required, please do comment if I could help further:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sdrrbj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: That's an interesting approach, and definitely helpful, but it feels like a clumsy workaround. The `input` element still has the `ng-valid` class, but you're introducing another class called `error`. The element says that it's both "valid" and "error", not good semantically, and a nuisance for managing the CSS.

Comment: I have spent time checking how this could be fixed but it appears to be Angular API issue. Please share if u have resolved this ?

Comment: @Snixtor : did u figure out yet?

Comment: Sadly, I have not found a better solution for this as yet. It seems like an odd omission in Angular. I would have thought this sort of component composition would be common.

Comment: Could you update the example link? I have the same problem with ng-invalid