# How to intercept ngClass property change event in an Angular 7 component?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, ng-class, angular-validation, angular-validator

I create a custom form control with validation as described here in [this blog](https://theinfogrid.com/tech/developers/angular/angular-build-custom-form-control/). The component is working and see the validation is applied to the component selector itself. I want the `ng-invalid` to be applied to the HTML element inside that component. I see this problem already described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093972/angular-child-component-ng-invalid).

A possible solution would be to intercept the event when the `ngClass` is changed, so it can be removed from the parent selector tag and add to the child element in the control.

How can I intercept the event that modify the property `ngClass` in the component?

Comment: What do you mean event? You are programmaticaly changing ngClass values, so your function changing it IS the "event".

Comment: When the validation fails in a reactive form, the ```ng-invalid``` class is added by the angular framework. Here is the [code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4c2ce4e8ba4c5ac5ce8754d67bc6603eaad4564a/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_control_status.ts) that does it.